# jquery: If statement not working inside ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a success function in my AJAX which returns the response text from a python script which can be either "SUCCESS" or "EMPTY". 
Now I want to place an if-loop inside the success function, but the if-loop is not working. I am getting the correct data from my python script because my alert statement is working fine and printing "SUCCESS". But it does not enter the ifloop

I have tried a bunch of things but the control is not entering the if-loop, could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/cgi-bin/getdataworld.py',
                    data: $(form).serialize(),

                    success: function(data) {
                            //document.write(result);
                            console.log("result is "+data);
                            alert(data);

                            if(data === "SUCCESS"){
                            window.location = 'index.html';
                               }
                           else{
                                 alert("NO DATA PRESENT");
                               }


                    },

                    error: function (responseData) {
                console.log('Ajax request not recieved!');
            }

                });

                return false;
            }
```

Comment: "if statement". It's not a loop. Also, are you sure there isn't any whitespace around "SUCCESS"? An alert won't always show the whitespace, or it can be difficult to see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This means that what you're responding with isn't `"SUCCESS"`. It probably has a line break or other whitespace before or after it, maybe more than one.

Perhaps:

```
if (/^\s*SUCCESS\s*$/.test(data)) {
    // Success
}
```

Or use jQuery's `$.trim`:

```
if ($.trim(data) === "SUCCESS") {
    // Success
}
```

Also be sure that you're not replying with `"Success"` or `"success"`, as string comparisons are case-sensitive.

If you're not sure:

```
if (/^\s*SUCCESS\s*$/i.test(data)) {
    // Success
}
```

or

```
if ($.trim(data).toUpperCase() === "SUCCESS") {
    // Success
}
```

Comment: could have read it wrong, but i am under the impression he is not getting in the IF or ELSE block at all.

Comment: @t.j.crowder This was the solution for my problem after hours of debugging! Thanks!

Comment: You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

check if you don't have any additional spaces before/after "SUCCESS"

And also try to change

```
if(data === "SUCCESS"){
```

to

```
if(data == "SUCCESS"){
```

Comment: `==` vs. `===` has no bearing whatsoever on whether `"SUCCESS"` equals `"\nSUCCESS"`.

Comment: you mean $.trim(data) i think

Comment: TJ: that's true - I've stated possible whitespaces problem at first - 2nd note was about that `===` is not really needed here

Comment: @JerzyZawadzki: Sorry, must have read right past it. It's too late over here, g'night. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , I am sharing my code of PHP and JavaScript here

PHP Code :

```
if(isset($result))
    $result_data['status']="success";
else
    $result_data['status']="failed";
 echo json_encode($result_data);
 die;
```

JavaScript code :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../ajax_check.php',
        data: data_added,
        success: function(data)
        {
 if(data['status']=="success"){
  $("#video-frame").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><h3>Successfully Added!</h3></div>');
          }
}
});
```

as you can see here I was using  **if(data['status']=="success")** due to this if condition could not executed. data['status'] comes with undefined not with success.

**Solution :**
**var data1 =  jQuery.parseJSON(data);** and use **data1.status instead of data1['status']**

```
var data1 =  jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          $("#video-frame .alert-success").remove();
          if(data1.status=="success"){
            $("#video-frame").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><h3>Call started with '+allow+'</h3></div>');
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/cgi-bin/getdataworld.py',
                data: $(form).serialize(),

                success: function(data1) {
                        //document.write(result);
                        console.log("result is "+data1);
                        alert(data1);

                        if(data1 == "SUCCESS"){
                        window.location = 'index.html';
                           }
                       else{
                             alert("NO DATA PRESENT");
                           }


                },

                error: function (responseData) {
            console.log('Ajax rariequest not recieved!');
        }

            });

            return false;
        }
```

try this here two things i noticed one is === in if statement and other you are using data as variable some time its conflicts in some browser