# jquery not working inside if after AJAX success/failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have just started learning AJAX 
Before posting I have already searched and refered to previous asked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710898/jquery-if-statement-not-working-inside-ajax-success-function) but it didn't helped 
well My Code is:

```
$('.del').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide('slow');
    $.get( "index.php", {del:$(this).attr('id')}).done(function(data){
        if (data==='1') {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

the jquery statements inside `if` as well as `else` is not executed To verify every thing is going well I had added an `alert` in the statements and it popped up successfully but the jquery statements isn't working.Whats The problem and how to fix this ?

Comment: Put this line `console.log(data);` on your `.done` function and post the output pls

Comment: The value of `this` inside the `.done()` callback is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your `$(this)` reference is incorrect in that scope. Try:

```
$('.del').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().hide('slow');
    $.get( "index.php", {del:$this.attr('id')}).done(function(data){
        if (data==='1') {
            $this.parent().remove();
        }
        else{
            $this.parent().show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well can you help me when I turn off server and then try to trigger it, it doesn't go to else part how can I make timeout or determine failure.

Comment: You may have access to use  .fail(function() { //do stuff}). Check out the docs. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be that your 'this' variable is out of scope in the callback. Try binding it, or use jQuery's `proxy()` [feature](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: While you are right about using `proxy` or `bind`, `this` has nothing to do with scope.